# access a UITextView in a function that did not create it and modify it

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a text view that is created

```
class viewController: UIViewController {


  var txtView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    txtView =  UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
    txtView.text = "hi"
    self.view.addSubview(txtView)
}
```

When the user pushes my app to the background (using the home button to switch to another app) and then returns to my app later I want to update the text in the text view.  I am trying this:

```
func updateText() {
  txtView.text = "bye"
}
```

and in my app delagate file I have

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  viewController().refreshAppInForeground()
}
```

When the user returns to my app it will not update the txtView

Comment: Since you are having instance variable, you can already identify it as unique, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SahilKapoor I am trying to update the text.  How do I access it in updateText() or is there a better way?

Comment: where is txt view declared? Isn't is a instance variable?

Comment: When the application comes to the foreground it looks like you are creating a new instance of your view controller and calling the method on that.  This is not the view controller you are showing but a completely different one.

Comment: @Abizern What part of my code creates the new view controller?  What should I do differently to access the already existing one?

Comment: This line `viewController().refreshAppInForeground()`, since your view controller class is called `viewController` instead of `ViewController` it makes it hard to spot. You should be accessing your existing view controller instance.

Comment: @Abizern I don't understand.  Both my class and what I am accessing are named 'viewController'.  What line of code should I modify to access my existing UIViewController?  And what do I change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this.

My problem seemed to be that applicationDidBecomeActive was firing too soon before it could reference my view.

However using a notification center listener solved it.

Here is a tutorial that I found helpful:
https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-implement-an-nsnotification-observer-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You can create your label as a property of your view controller with an empty frame.

```
var txtView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

And you can give it a frame in the `viewWillAppear` function as you have already done:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // Don't forget the call to super
    // Set the frame for your textview
    txtView =  UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
    txtView.text = "hi"
    view.addSubview(txtView)
}
```

Since the textview is a property on the view controller, you now have access to it.

Comment: This works really well as long as the app is in the foreground.  If it goes into the backgound via user switching apps and then reenters the foreground I cannot seem to access this global variable.  I try to access it through a method called in applicationDidBecomeActive but it cannot find it.

Comment: Are you sure the view controller has been created again?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening to the view controller.  Do I need to rebuild the whole thing?  Happy to do that if you know how..  Basically this is the steps I am taking.  1.  Load the app.  2.  Go to the view controller with the txtView code.  3.  Hit the home button 4.  Reopen the app.  It loads the same view controller, but does not update the view as expected

Comment: If there is a way to just destroy the view controller and make it reload the whole thing I would be totally happy with that

Comment: I can't tell what you are doing without code. Are you using any State Restoration methods?

Comment: I updated the above to illustrate it better with code.